# Get text of html tag where child tag value equals something

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a website that I want to scrape, and I have a part of the website where the HTML is like so:

```html
<p class="abc xyz">
    <em class="efg">Whatever:</em> 
    test                        
</p>
<p class="abc xyz">
    <em class="efg">Phone:</em> 
    +1-111-222-3333
</p>
```

I only want to get the `text` of the `p` tag where the `em` tag's text, inside the `p` tag, is `Phone`. So in the example above, I want to save `+1-111-222-3333`.

The classes are all the same, and the structure is the same also, but I don't need any other data other then the `phone`.

Is there any way that I can do this, or do I have to just save all the data, and then remove it in my `csv` file afterwards?

Comment: How about you check elements recursively, and whenever you find a paragraph, test whether the first child is em and contains "Phone:", and if that's true, push the second element's text to your csv? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: You might be right. Didn't think about it like this. I started thinking about more complicated solutions and just missed this one. Thanks :)

Comment: Well uh, no problem good sir. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to parse it with specific tools and prefer simple string search, you can try below regex search.

```regex
<p[^>]*>\s*<em[^>]*>\s*Phone[^<]*<\/em>\s*(.*)\s*<\/p>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qXFmxC/1)

**Example code**

```py
import re

html="""
<p class="abc xyz">
    <em class="efg">Whatever:</em> 
    test                        
</p>
<p class="abc xyz">
    <em class="efg">Phone:</em> 
    +1-111-222-3333
</p>
"""

print(re.findall("<p[^>]*>\s*<em[^>]*>\s*Phone[^<]*<\/em>\s*(.*)\s*<\/p>",html))
```

**Output**

```
['+1-111-222-3333']
```

Answer (score 0):

create list of all parent tag:

```
t = """
<p class="abc xyz">
    <em class="efg">Whatever:</em> 
    test                        
</p>
<p class="abc xyz">
    <em class="efg">Phone:</em> 
    +1-111-222-3333
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(t)
result = soup.find_all('p',class_='abc xyz')
```

the `result` would be a list of with parent tag `p` here with class `abc xyz` i.e.

```
[<p class="abc xyz">
 <em class="efg">Whatever:</em> 
     test                        
 </p>,
 <p class="abc xyz">
 <em class="efg">Phone:</em> 
     +1-111-222-3333
 </p>]
```

now iterate over the list, and compare the text of child tag that you want, here->"Phone:"

```
for iter in result:
    if (iter.find('em').text)=='Phone:':
        print(iter.text.replace("\n","").split(" ")[-1])
```

this would give the result:*+1-111-222-3333*

if you check result[0].text then you get:
`'\nWhatever: \n    test                        \n'`

and result[1].text:`'\nPhone: \n    +1-111-222-3333\n'`
it contains newline so just replace them.